# Cloud Endpoints in Java on GAE (not javascript)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Although I do think Cloud Endpoints are quite nifty, it would be great if I could use them directly in my GWT application in Java code, rather than writing masses of JSNI. Is this possible? I cannot find a way.

In other words, I would like to NOT use the Javascript Endpoints client, but all the endpoint methods using Java inside GWT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a simple request using Java's built-in `HttpURLConnection` object. Something like this:

```
//The URL would be the one you see when you execute the method from APIs Explorer...
String stringURL = "https://YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/API_NAME/VERSION/METHOD_PATH?param1=xxx&param2=yyy";

URL url = new URL(stringURL); 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

And then you could parse the response, using [**Google's Gson library**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example (but that would be another question...).

*Note: I've never tried this, but I understand it should be working... If you eventually try it, please comment...*